# *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I keep getting this error:

> 2017-10-18 22:57:52.401421+0300 Expense Manager[4213:133067] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'

But I have no idea what did I do wrong. The **tableView** works just fine when **numberOfSections** is **1** and they are not sorted by date, but when I try and do sections for each day, it crashes on app launch.

```
  func userBudgetCount(_ section: Int) -> Int {
            return fetchedResultsController.sections![section].numberOfObjects
        }

        func getUserBudgetAtIndexPath(indexPath : IndexPath) -> Budget {
            return fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as Budget
        }


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.hideKeyboard()

            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self

            self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()


        }

        override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)
            fetchCoreDataObject()
            tableView.reloadData()

        }

        func fetchCoreDataObject() {
            self.fetch { (complete) in
                if complete {
                    if userBudgetCount(0) >= 1 {
                        userBudgetLabel.text = replaceLabel(number: userMoney[userMoney.count - 1].userMoney)
                        tableView.isHidden = false
                        plusButton.isHidden = false
                        moreBtn.isHidden = false
                    } else {
                        tableView.isHidden = true
                        userBudgetLabel.text = "Bugetul tau"
                        plusButton.isHidden = true
                        moreBtn.isHidden = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Budget> {
            if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
                return _fetchedResultsController!
            }

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Budget>(entityName: "Budget")

            // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
            fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

            // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateSubmitted" , ascending: false)

            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

            // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
            // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
            let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: "dateSection", cacheName: nil)
            aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
            _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

            do {
                try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }

            return _fetchedResultsController!
        }
        var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Budget>? = nil

        func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
     func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return fetchedResultsController.sections!.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "expenseCell") as? ExpenseCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
            let budget = getUserBudgetAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath)
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.configureCell(budget: budget)
            return cell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
            return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.none
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return userBudgetCount(section)
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
            return "Section: \(section)"
        }
```

Comment: Which line is it crashing? As mentioned in error, you have an empty array and you are trying to access its first index.

Comment: I don't know which line is crashing, it takes me to AppDelegate when it crashes. Doesn't say the line

Comment: Add the exception breakpoint

Comment: @vadian https://i.imgur.com/VWWrGqs.png

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/xcode/how-to-create-exception-breakpoints-in-xcode

Comment: Ok so I set the **sectionKeyPath** to **nil**, the app works fine, I input some data, close the app, switch the **sectionKeyPath** back to **dateSection** and it all just works fine. I gotta find a fix to skip the loading of **tableView** if the **count** is **0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

The problem was not in the `tableView` populating functions, but in the function I try to check **if there is an element in my entity** so I can make my **tableView** visible

In this code

```
  func fetchCoreDataObject() {
            self.fetch { (complete) in
                if complete {
                    if userBudgetCount(0) >= 1 {
                        userBudgetLabel.text = replaceLabel(number: userMoney[userMoney.count - 1].userMoney)
                        tableView.isHidden = false
                        plusButton.isHidden = false
                        moreBtn.isHidden = false
                    } else {
                        tableView.isHidden = true
                        userBudgetLabel.text = "Bugetul tau"
                        plusButton.isHidden = true
                        moreBtn.isHidden = true
                    }
                }
            }
```

I try to check **userBudgetCount(0)** which is out of bounds because there is **NO** section 0 at the moment I try to check if it exists. So what I needed was to check if my **fetchedResultsController** has any objects or not, so I replaced the  `if userBudgetCount(0) >= 1` with `if ((fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.count)! > 0)` and it works fine now. Thank you everyone for answering!

Comment: Nice try. But this will not guarantee crash free code. What will happen if you pass a number greater than total section count from anywhere inside project? You could follow my answer. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean pass a number greater than total section count? I'm passing the object numbers, not the sections

Answer (score 0):

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
guard let count = fetchedResultsController.sections?.count else {return 1}
return count
}
Try to safe unwrap:

Answer (score 0):

When your view first loads the table view data source methods start getting called before the results controller has acquired any data. As a result anywhere you are force unwrapping something you are likely to get a crash.

To fix this look through every spot you do a forced unwrap (everywhere you use `!`) and do something more like this:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
}
```

That will make sure *something* gets returned without the risk of a crash. In some places you may have a more challenging time figuring out what the default return value should be, but it should be doable.

The `??` operator is called the nil-coalescing operator. The syntax works like below:

```
let foo = someOptionalThing ?? defaultThing
```

If `someOptionalThing` has a value it gets assigned to `foo` otherwise `defaultThing` gets assigned to `foo`.

### Update based on your comments:

Looks like you call `return fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as Budget` the results controller has no objects yet which is what I was expecting.

```
func getUserBudgetAtIndexPath(indexPath : IndexPath) -> Budget {
    // Make sure the section exists
    guard fetchedResultsController.sections?.count > indexPath.section else { return Budget() }
    // Make sure the section has enough objects
    guard fetchedResultsController.sections[indexPath.section].objects?.count > indexPath.row else { return Budget() }
    // We made it past both guards, must be safe
    return fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath) as Budget
}
```

Comment: You tried changing _every_ place that you do a forced unwrap or you copied the method I showed above? You mentioned that particular method as being the one you changed from returning a hard coded `1` but doesn't access an element of an array so it is unlikely to be the actual cause of your issue.

Comment: I copied the line. I tried to do the same to other force unwraps but they are weird variables to me like **NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo** which I don't know what default value should I use

Comment: My guess is that your issue is in either `userBudgetCount` or `getUserBudgetAtIndexPath`. Those are the methods that access arrays either directly or indirectly. Add a break point to each of them and when they get triggered use Step Over and see if it makes it past the line or crashes. If you get a crash you will know where the issue is and add a guard to project against it.

Comment: `userBudgetCount` works fine with breakpoints but when I add a breakpoint to `getUserBudgetAtIndexPath` function I get thrown out by the index beyond bounds, so the code can't call that function somehow, otherwise my app wouldve stopped due to my breakpoint

Comment: Xcode put me to unwrap some of those values, otherwise the code wouldn't build. This is what I unwrapped  `guard fetchedResultsController.sections!.count > indexPath.section` and `guard fetchedResultsController.sections![indexPath.section].objects!.count > indexPath.row`

Code still giving me the same error.

Comment: At this point you are going to have to add an exception break point like Vadian suggested ages ago. Then you will be able to see the stack trace of where the exception is being thrown. Look down the trace until you see some of your code and that is the culprit. It is also possible that more than one place is throwing the same error and when you fix one the next one gets triggered.

Comment: Maybe there is somewhere else an error in my code. I'm leaving here the full source code, if you find anything please let me know: https://pastebin.com/2zTvyk5d ; https://pastebin.com/af0Empst

Comment: The exception break point gives me https://i.imgur.com/rzhh0C2.png and I don't understand what this is

Comment: @AndreiVataselu, see the area on the left that has the breakpoints listed? Look at the icons along the top and find the blue one. Then click on the left (called the debug navigator). You want to look at that area when the exception is thrown as that is where the call stacks for all the threads will be shown. The thread that triggered the breakpoint should be open.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Actually problem is in `userBudgetCount` method. This method is called with 0 parameter
Value from `fetchCoreDataObject` method which is throwing exception because sections array is empty initially.

Replace uncommentthis function with below lines of code. Note these lines of code is not compiled yet.

```
func userBudgetCount(_ section: Int) -> Int{
 guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections           else {
     fatalError("No sections in   fetchedResultsController")
  // comment out the above line of  and  rerun 0 if don’t want to catch  exception 
  // rerun 0;
  }
    let sectionInfo = sections[section]
  return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}
```

**EDIT** After compiling on my side, I've added updated code at below. Please use it instead of above.

```
func userBudgetCount(_ section: Int) -> Int{
    guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else {
        return 0;
    }

    if sections.count > section{
        let sectionInfo = sections[section]
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting `Value of type 'NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo' has no member 'object'`

Comment: @AndreiVataselu I’ve updated my answer. NSFetchResultsSectionInfo is a protocol which has a property called objects[array]. Get items from there, see my updated answer. Thanks

Comment: Now I'm getting `Value of type '[Any]?' has no member 'object'`

Comment: @AndreiVataselu I’m sorry for giving wrong answer. Please see my latest answer

Comment: Don't be sorry, I'm grateful that you are trying to help me. Unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: @AndreiVataselu did you corrected getUserBudgetAtIndexPath with previous sources? Get back with earlier source and modify only userBudgetCout method.

Comment: How should I correct **getUserBudgetAtIndexPath** ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157081/discussion-between-shamim-hossain-and-andreivataselu).

Comment: Thank you but I managed to solve it now. Check my answer to see what the problem was